# How to find all the clickable elements using Appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am now working on Android Automation Test using Appium, and today when I was trying to find all the clickable elements in an android app page, I use the following code referenced from [appium/java-client](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/171fcca4a546ccf1ab3c2afb1010b01510f59689/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/AndroidUIAutomatorTest.java#L50):

```
List<WebElement> Elements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
Elements = driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().clickable(true)"));
```

But Eclipse keeps reporting error in the second line:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#4-of ?> to List<WebElement>`

I tried to add cast `(List<WebElement>)` but it does not work well. Anyone has some ideas? Thx.